# Oracle dynamic join (or move row)

Tags: oracle, join, plsql, dynamically-generated

I'm running **Oracle 11g** and need to separate certain rows into columns but the number of columns is undetermined, so I need to do it dynamically.

Initially I thought of separating into multiple queries and joining them later but it doesn't seem the most appropriate and I'm having trouble making it dynamic.

This is a simplified example of my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id NUMBER,
    cod NUMBER,
    val NUMBER,
    dat DATE
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1, 35, 58.10, TO_DATE('01-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(2, 45, 38.50, TO_DATE('01-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(3, 45, 3.89, TO_DATE('20-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(4, 35, 102.0, TO_DATE('01-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(5, 75, 69.32, TO_DATE('01-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(6, 75, 74.65, TO_DATE('01-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(7, 45, 32.8, TO_DATE('01-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(8, 75, 12.76, TO_DATE('01-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1, 35, 38.50, TO_DATE('01-08-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(2, 45, 3.89, TO_DATE('01-08-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(3, 45, 102.0, TO_DATE('01-08-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(4, 35, 69.32, TO_DATE('01-08-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(5, 75, 74.65, TO_DATE('01-08-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(6, 75, 32.8, TO_DATE('01-08-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(7, 45, 38.50, TO_DATE('30-08-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(8, 75, 3.89, TO_DATE('01-08-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));

SELECT a.cod, a.val, b.cod, b.val 
FROM foo a, (
    SELECT id, cod, val
    FROM foo
    WHERE dat = TO_DATE('01-07-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
) b
WHERE a.id = b.id AND 
    a.dat = TO_DATE('01-08-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

output (sort by COD):

```
COD|VAL  |COD|VAL  |
---|-----|---|-----|
 35| 38.5| 35| 58.1|
 35|69.32| 35|  102|
 45| 3.89| 45| 38.5|
 75|74.65| 75|69.32|
 75| 32.8| 75|74.65|
 75| 3.89| 75|12.76|
```

I need the rows to have only one distinct COD the others will be arranged in new columns.

Expected:

```
      COD 35       |      COD 45       |      COD 75       | <- illustrative
-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
COD|VAL  |COD|VAL  |COD|VAL  |COD|VAL  |COD|VAL  |COD|VAL  |
---|-----|---|-----|---|-----|---|-----|---|-----|---|-----|
 35| 38.5| 35| 58.1| 45| 3.89| 45| 38.5| 75|74.65| 75|69.32|
 35|69.32| 35|  102|   |     |   |     | 75| 32.8| 75|74.65|
   |     |   |     |   |     |   |     | 75| 3.89| 75|12.76|
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to use dynamic query in that case as number COD is not defined in advance

Comment: @Tejash, how can I make the loop for CODs using dynamic query?

Comment: What is the logic for associating each pair of records?  For example, for COD 35, what are values 38.5 and 58.1 associated with each other and not associated with 69.32 or 102?  Also, why is 38.5 on the left and 58.1 on the right?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak the main idea is to improve readability, this table has thousands of rows so its size is proportional to the amount of COD. I cannot aggregate the values because there are other values from another table, in fact the example table has another id for this relationship. The values on the left are from last month and to the right of the current month (I made the mistake of inverting in the example but it makes no difference) and are used for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with de following:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_cod_str VARCHAR2(100) := '35, 75, 45';
  i_prv VARCHAR2(10);
  q_loop VARCHAR2(1000);
  q_select VARCHAR2(1000);
  q_where VARCHAR2(1000);
  q_from VARCHAR2(5000);
  q_query VARCHAR2(5000);
BEGIN
    -- split cods string by comma
    FOR i IN (
            SELECT trim(regexp_substr(p_cod_str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) cod
            FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(p_cod_str, ',') + 1
    ) LOOP
        q_loop := 'SELECT rownum as rn, a.id as id, 
            a.cod AS cod_a_' || i.cod || ', a.val AS val_a_' || i.cod || ', 
            b.cod AS cod_b_' || i.cod || ', b.val AS val_b_' || i.cod || ' 
            FROM foo a, (
                SELECT id, cod, val
                FROM foo
                WHERE dat = TO_DATE(''01-07-2019'', ''DD-MM-YYYY'')
            ) b
            WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.cod = ' || i.cod || ' AND
                a.dat = TO_DATE(''01-08-2019'', ''DD-MM-YYYY'')
        ';

        q_select := q_select || ', 
            t_' || i.cod || '.cod_a_' || i.cod || ', t_' || i.cod || '.val_a_' || i.cod || ', 
            t_' || i.cod || '.cod_b_' || i.cod || ', t_' || i.cod || '.val_b_' || i.cod;

        IF q_from IS NULL THEN
            q_from := ' (
                ' || q_loop || '
            ) t_' || i.cod;
        ELSE
            q_from := q_from || '
            FULL OUTER JOIN (
                ' || q_loop || '
            ) t_' || i.cod || '
            ON t_' || i_prv || '.rn = t_' || i.cod || '.rn';
        END IF;

        i_prv := i.cod;
    END LOOP;

    -- mount query
    q_query := 'SELECT ' || ltrim(q_select, ', ') 
        || ' FROM ' || q_from;

    dbms_output.put_line('query: ' || q_query);
END;
```

It will generate the SQL and with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` I can run it.

Result:

```
COD_A_35|VAL_A_35|COD_B_35|VAL_B_35|COD_A_75|VAL_A_75|COD_B_75|VAL_B_75|COD_A_45|VAL_A_45|COD_B_45|VAL_B_45|
--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
      35|    38.5|      35|    58.1|      75|   74.65|      75|   69.32|      45|    3.89|      45|    38.5|
      35|   69.32|      35|     102|      75|    32.8|      75|   74.65|        |        |        |        |
        |        |        |        |      75|    3.89|      75|   12.76|        |        |        |        |
```

Thanks folks for the tips